# Server for android game (design)

Tags: android, database, server

This is a design question.

I have an online game that I am designing currently, to eliminate details it's essentially a game where the user tries to make the most amount of money within a time limit. I don't need to persist data at all, so if a player played a game and made 20 million dollars and leaves the game then I don't need to save it and send it the user when they come back later. All data saved for the client is done up to the point until they leave the game. So I'll do a run through of a session in the game to have a better understanding.

The player opens the app and inputs a name they want to use and clicks start game.

The player name is sent to the server and the server saves the player name and generates a player id (this is unique id) and sends the player id and the data needed to play the game to the user.

The player plays the game and in the background the application sends requests to the server to update it's "money count" and to get back it's rank.
The server updates the client's data and sends back the player's rank (amongst all the players playing online).

I'll stop here because my question is about the data on the server side. Obviously using tables is a bad choice since I don't need to persist the data and it's going to be a fast pace game so querying a remote database will be heavy on performance. So I'm very new to client-server interactions so I'm not sure how else the data can be stored on the server side. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is filled with contradictions. However, I'll do my best to answer.

I would consider using [Google Play Game Services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/games.html) for such an app. Google Game Services capabilities include real-time support, leaderboards and multi-user. Another multiple-user option might be [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html). Finally, you could use a simple rest API, say with PHP or rails, and store data in a database (table) on server side (e.g. Mongo, MySQL, Oracle etc).